# What is the difference between fragmentTransaction.remove and setVisibility(GONE);

Tags: android, android-fragments

What is the better practice for removing fragments (when the animation is not required) using 
fragmentTransaction.remove 
or 
changing the fragment container view visibility to GONE - setVisibility(GONE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the fragment will cause the entire fragment to be destroyed (onStop and onDestroy will be called).

Setting the visiblity to GONE will only hide the view from the user. The fragment instance will still exist and run through life cycle events.

Comment: The reason I asked this is because I need to hide the fragment immediately, and I don't want to wait till the transaction is done as it causes a delay. So I was thinking about this scenario then:
1. setVisibility(GONE)
2. fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment)
But I'm afraid it will cause life cycle events collision then...

Comment: @Drimmka setVisibility(GONE) does not trigger life cycle events.  It might be useful to know that a ViewTreeObserver can let you know when the visibility of a view changes.

Comment: Are you concerned with the visual delay to the user? If so, that delay should be impossible to notice because the removal will typically fire in the next few milliseconds. The only way this would take a long time is if you are doing some lengthy [bad] tasks on the main thread. All that being said, there won't be a problem with hiding the fragment before removing it.